# Unnecessary comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Should I keep my comments or remove them if they are wrong or no longer serve a purpose under an answer/question?

When I remove my comment(s), the other comments (by others) become meaningless. If those comments are also removed, it looks cleaner to me. If not, it feels awkward to ask to remove them.

Comment: Good Question, Comments are more for clarifying the question or answer, once the question or answer have been fully clarified they are obsolete and should be deleted.  Remember that anything in a comment may be deleted at any time, anything of importance to the Question or answer should be edited in by the original post's author.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure you can remove them. If you feel other comments are left in an awkward state, then [feel free to flag them as obsolete](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1686/120114). That way a moderator will review them and remove them if deemed appropriate.

[image]

[There is also a SE meta post about flagging whole comment conversations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182684/341145), which you may find relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes, yes.   Not only *can* you decide to remove your own comments that are incorrect or no longer relevant, I strongly advocate that volunteers SHOULD ALWAYS remove their comments that are incorrect or no longer relevant.

By removing yours, you enable the removal of the "response" comments that trail it.  This is always a good thing.

This logic goes applies to other volunteers' comments.

Always consider that every comment is as valuable as toilet paper -- to be disposed of, without a trace, as soon as it has served its purpose.

This bleeds through to other page-bloating comments like "thanks" and "+1" and "you are a God-like genius" and even worse commented solutions that disturb researcher focal points and defy StackExchange design.

All of these comments (and more which do not improve content) should be swiftly removed/flagged with extreme prejudice.

In fact, when you can edit a question or answer by including useful comments (and reference the commenter of course) in the post itself, then the comment can be removed and everybody wins.

In a utopian page, there are no comments.  This is Q & A not Q & A & C.  Let complete and comprehensive questions and answers do their thing.  Beautiful.

Comment: What do you mean by "*disturb researcher focal points*"?

Comment: When researchers come to Q & A, they "expect" to find a complete question / full story in the question position (not scattered details among the question body, comments under the question, and/or under answers). Likewise, the focal point for solutions / answers should be in answer positions, as opposed to a primary answer followed by a thread of back and forth dialogue about fringe cases, justifications, and affiliated advice.  Researchers enjoy an optimized experience when complete and comprehensive posts are packaged concisely where purposely designed.