# Thanking someone for a good code review

Tags: discussion, comments

Is it appropriate to comment on a good Code Review answer to one of my posts with a "Thank you"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are multiple things you can do, most of which unfortunately require reputation.

## [Accept an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts)

If you think one answer is better than the rest, then you can accept the answer by selecting the hollowed out tick under the voting buttons. This gives the answer 15 reputation.

## [Vote Up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

At 15 reputation you possess the ability to up-vote questions and answers. This gives an answer 10 reputation. If you think the answer is good make sure you've up-voted!

## [Start a bounty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

At 75 reputation you can start a bounty giving 50-500 of your own reputation to an answer.

---

If you wish to give something to an answerer it's encouraged to give the up-vote and the accept. (25 reputation)

As an answerer, I always enjoy it when a user gives a warm thank you. If it's one comment I don't think it's 'too chatty', but expect no response from the answerer, as then you'd both be 'too chatty'.

Comment: Some comments that are written as a detailed thank you are a really nice read, and usually tends to stay around for longer.

Comment: Can you give more reputation than you have? Or all of it (e.g. you're at 100 rep and you give all of it in a bounty)?

Comment: @JL2210 I do not know. But I would assume it would only allow you to post a 100 point bounty only if you have 101 or more points - lowest reputation is 1 not 0.

Answer (score 8):

No - such comments are [too chatty](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1686/120114). You should [vote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) accordingly. And if you have enough reputation, you could consider starting and awarding [a bounty](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

The Help Center page [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) states the following under the heading **What should I *not* do?**:

> **Please refrain from posting a comment that merely says "thank you."** Voting and accepting are the preferred ways of saying "thank you" on this site, as they confer reputation points. Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information—not for socializing.

Also, from the Help Center page for [the Comment Privilege](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

[image: screen capture]

or for brevity/posterity:

> #### When *shouldn't* I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer);

Answer (score 6):

I would argue that it feels *nice* to get a comment like "thank you so much, I had no idea X was Y and you made me realize Z". In fact, this feels much *nicer* than just a +1 which could come from anyone (or a bot for all I know).

But at the same time, everyone should realize that comments are always temporary. That is, if I add a "thank you" comment, I make sure to remove it after a day or two once the person it was given to has seen it. Also, if I see such comments anywhere after several days, I flag them for being too chatty.